# Using Git to manage assets/db of a project

Tags: git, version-control

We are implementing Git at our company and coming from SVN, I have a few architectural questions.

For our designers, how can they manage project assets? Documents, PDFs, PSDs, graphics? In SVN we could just make a folder called 'assets', detached from the code.

How can you do the same for a db snapshot?

I want to keep code seperate from digital assets without creating more overhead or making it complicated for our designers to version control their work.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your "just make a folder called 'assets'" remark. Did you not store the folder in SVN and use .svnignore? If yes, then do the same with GIT and .gitignore.

Comment: No, we had people putting design files into assets to version control them. So say, Designer A creates design_psd_1.psd, commits it, Designer B picks it up from the assets folder. We want people to be able to access design files from anywhere at anytime. Or are digital assets in general not good for version control?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand your question, previously the assets were part of your subversion repository and designers only checked out the `assets` directory because they did not need the source code.  The exactly same approach does not work in git because git does not support partial checkouts, so designers would have to bother checking out the source code as well, and you would like to avoid this.  Right?

The best approximation of your old scheme would be to put the assets in a separate git repository and include this separate repository as a [module](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) in your source repository.  Developers would have everything in one place, and designers could check out the assets only.